# Symfony2 - 404 for some URLs With Apache, Nginx ok

Tags: php, apache, symfony, routes

I encounter a problem with Symfony2 on prod. More specifically, it  is an API built with FosRestBundle, and my problem occurs only for one URL: api.domain.com/user/{id}. This service returns data for the user with the given {id}. There is also in the routing a default id = 0, in order to return the current user data when {id} isn't passed in the URL.

On dev, everything works well. On prod, I can get data for some users, but not all of them. Especially /user without {id} isn't working. But /user/0 is ok (which returns in both cases the data for the current user). /0 ok /1 ok /2 ok /3 no, /4 ok... etc. All those users exist, and I can't understand why it returns a 404 service not found, which occurs before the controller.

That could be a bad configuration of my server (apache2.4) but I don't think so / don't see where. Rewrite work, cache is cleared, router:debug gives the same on prod & dev, etc.
However, I'm using nginx locally and I don't have this problem when I use the prod environment. That's why I think it could be dependent of my remote apache server config, but it sounds strange. I'm also thinking of some doctrine problem.

Maybe someone has an idea ?

**EDIT**:
If I replace in my routing file /user by /userr or /xyz, everything works. It seems like a conflict in routes. I have another /user route but using a different method, so I dont think that comes from this. Moreover, changing both patterns to /something is working.

My current not working routing on prod:

```
my_api_user_get:
pattern:  /user/{id}.{_format}
defaults: { _controller: MyApiBundle:User:user, id: 0, _format: ~ }
requirements:
    #here it's post because I pass some params in the body
    _method: POST
    id:  \d+

my_api_user_delete:
pattern:  /user.{_format}
defaults: { _controller: MyApiBundle:User:delete, _format: ~ }
requirements:
    _method: DELETE
```

If I change patterns for /something, all works (my_api_user_get with `pattern:  /something/{id}.{_format}` & my_api_user_delete with `pattern:  /something.{_format}`)

**EDIT2**: for the 3 following router:match commands, I get the same correct result:

```
$ router:match /user --host="api.domain.com" --method="POST"
$ router:match /user/2 --host="api.domain.com" --method="POST"
$ router:match /user/3 --host="api.domain.com" --method="POST"
```

give me:

```
[router] Route "my_api_user_get"
Name         my_api_user_get
Path         /user/{id}.{_format}
Host         api.domain.com
Scheme       ANY
Method       POST
Class        Symfony\Component\Routing\Route
Defaults     _controller: myApiBundle:User:user
             _format: NULL
             id: 0
Requirements id: \d+
Options      compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler
Path-Regex   #^/user(?:/(?P<id>\d+)(?:\.(?P<_format>[^/]++))?)?$#s
Host-Regex   #^api\.domain\.com$#s
```

I also noticed that this problem occurs on others routes with parameters (but strangely it was ok before, and I haven't changed nothing).
+ I saw that for the problematic urls, such /user/3, or /user, it generates a **redirect 301** to /user/3**/** or /user**/**, while /user/1 or /user/2 work normally. I don't understand from where this redirect comes from.

**Edit 3**
It was an Apache config problem. I still don't know exactly why it acts like that, but I have the solution. Concretely apache added some / on some urls, and not on some others. To solve that, I just added a .htaccess at the root, with the following info :

```
Options -Multiviews -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: the only routes that do not work are /user and /user/3?  Have you checked that the route matching /user is defined on the prod.  For the /user/3 case, can you go to the dev and check the route that matches it, and make sure it is the route you are thinking of?

Comment: Yes for now they are the only routes that give problems. However I have just 6 users, and can't create much more to test, as it depends of facebook users currently admins of a development fb application. My route file is the same for dev & prod. However I just noticed that changing /user by /anything is working. I've edited my question with more info about this

Comment: What do you mean by *"I have another /user route but using a different method"* ? If you defined 2 routes using the same pattern, you're gonna have issues for sure !

Comment: You're right, but one is waiting for an {id} after the /user, so it is not really the same pattern, and they don't have the same http method. I just thought that it could be the source of the problem. However, replacing /user by /something in both routes is working good.

Comment: to avoid blanks in your variables for routes, do nto use a ~.  use a placeholder by `_format: htm` so that this route will not get confused with /user.   Use the dev tools to check which route matches so you can verify the correct controller is used.

Comment: I tested with _format: json but it's the same problem. I had previously in the FosRestBundle config the _format set to json automatically. I edited again my question, the route seems to match, but I noticed that the problem occurs on other urls with ids, and that the problem comes from a redirect 301 adding a / at the end